# Save value of textInputs on call function React-Native

Tags: react-native, state, textinput

I am fetching some TextInputs from an API and pushing them to an Array. Then I am saving the input text from user and all keys and values that a textinput object has. However, when I save, it saves every time I make a change on the text. I want to save and push everything to the array when I call a function further down in View. Basically, I want the state to be pushed to array only once I call a function, not every time I change text.

I appreciate any suggestion! Please let me know if the question is not clear enough.

```
myInputFields = {
   myTextFields: [],
};

textfieldsObject = () => {
const obje = this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
var keyvalue_to_json = JSON.parse(obje.keyValues);
var foundTextFields = [];

for (let i = 0; i < keyvalue_to_json.inputFields.length; i++) {
  if (keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].type === 'textfield') {
    foundTextFields.push(<TextInput style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}

      onChangeText={(text) => {
        keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].inputValues = text;
        this.myInputFields.myTextFields.push(keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i])
      }}
    >{keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].placeholderText}</TextInput>)</Text>)
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[onChangeText](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchangetext) event will be invoked every time when you type or change text. You need to use [onEndEditing](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onendediting) event which is triggered only when the text input ends. So your `TextInput` code will be:

```
<TextInput style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
  onEndEditing={(e) => {
    keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].inputValues = e.nativeEvent.text;
    this.myInputFields.myTextFields.push(keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i])
  }}
>{keyvalue_to_json.inputFields[i].placeholderText}
</TextInput>
```

Comment: It works in a way. If I write some thing in textinputs, and print them, it prints all textinputs once only, so that's good. But when I try to change the value in a text input before calling the other function, it prints that textinput's object twice, because I made changes in that twice. How can I stop it doing that?

Comment: Do you have a solution to that problem?

Comment: Will you respond to my question?

Comment: Please do it asap, I really need it! :(

Comment: You need to write logic to avoid duplicate. Make `myTextFields` as a key value pair (object). If key doesn't exist, add it. If exists, replace it with new value.